# Swig returns 'No module name specified' error when including c++ code in python

Tags: python, swig

I would like to include C++ code in python and decided to use swig.

I followed the example from the [tutorial](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn4) on the swig-site.

```
/* File: example.i */
%module example

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "example.h"
%}

int fact(int n);
```

.

```
/* File: example.c */

#include "example.h"

int fact(int n) {
    if (n < 0){ /* This should probably return an error, but this is simpler */
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        /* testing for overflow would be a good idea here */
        return n * fact(n-1);
    }
}
```

.

```
/* File: example.h */

int fact(int n);
```

If if I then run the command to wrap it, I get the following.

```
swig -c++ -python example.i
No module name specified using %module or -module.
```

How can I circumvent that?

Comment: The example is perfectly ok as stated and works fine. Something else must be the problem, but honestly, I cannot guess what that might be.

Comment: Solved it... Txtfile example.i was not saved...